# Error Handling when Contacting 3rd Party APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, error-handling

Given i have the following contrived code in a Rails controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @profile = current_user.profile
    @content_from_third_party_api = @profile.get_that_third_party_content
  end
end
```

This code in a `views/profiles/show.html.haml`:

```
%h1
  Profile Page!
%h2
  Data from 3rd party:
= @content_from_third_party_api.first.title
```

And this contrived code for `#get_that_third_party_content`:

```
def get_that_third_party_content
  uri = URI.parse("http://api.somesite.com/imfake/")

  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  response = http.request(request)

  case response.code.to_i
  when 200 # the happy path
    response
  when (400..499)
    # What should I do/return here?  I have nothing useful to return to the caller.
  when (500..599)
    # Same goes for here...
  end
end
```

How do I elegantly handle timeouts/errors/etc in `#get_that_third_party_content` given the following:

- The show view expects `@content_from_third_party_api` to NOT be nil.  If it's nil i'll get NilClass errors all over the place
- The show view needs to render Something
- `#get_that_third_party_content` will return nothing if there's an error
- It feels like i need to be doing a lot of nil checking... and this seems really wrong
- `rescue_from` seems like a good solution but I'm not sure if this is good

Comment: If you timeout, `render` a different page explaining that something went wrong and to try again later. You could also store any information that you receive from these APIs and return the stored information if you timeout, error, etc.

Comment: Is there a pattern for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll likely want to use something like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) here, because you can leverage middleware. Creating a Faraday builder is fairly straightforward and you can write middlewares to handle all of your concerns. There is native middleware for timeouts (just require it) and exception handling.

Given you want to "elegantly" handle these use cases, middleware seems like the most logical option to me. Otherwise, as you've indicated, you're going to have complex branching logic in your controller.

```
# lib/requestor.rb
require 'faraday'
require 'faraday_middleware' # optional, but nice: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday_middleware

# This is just one example. There are literally hundreds of ways to use
# Faraday, and the documentation is quite good.
class APIConnector
  attr_reader :connection

  def initialize(url)
    @connection = Faraday.new(url) do |connection|
      # Set up your connection here (like response and request objects).
      # There are a lot of examples in the Faraday documentation and things
      # really depend on the API you are accessing.
      #
      # You can set things like timeouts, retrys, mashes, rashes, etc.

      # Set some options, such as timeouts
      connection.options[:timeout]      = 10
      connection.options[:open_timeout] = 10
    end
  end

  def get(path)
    connection.get(path)
  end
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @profile = current_user.profile
    response = requestor.get('/path')

    if response.success?
      @third_party_content = response.body
    else
      # This changes depending on the volatility of your application. 
      # You might raise an error, show a flash message, kill the 
      # request, etc. It all depends on the context.
      render text: 'API Request failed'
    end
  end

  private

  def requestor
    @requestor ||= Requestor.new(some_url)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but a code example and/or pattern that can be used would be Super helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So is it safe to say that no matter what there will be at least 1 logic branch that essentially checks if a request fails then renders something for the user to view?  I ask because while researching this issue i've seen lots of people using `rescue_from` and raising a specific error.  This seems to keep the controller actions free of logic.

Comment: Right - you'll need at least one. Unless you push that down into the middleware stack and raise exceptions. And then have global rescue_from handlers that gracefully fix that

Comment: Seth, thanks a lot for updating the answer! I've been reading your blog posts for help with this w/o realizing that you're also answering my questions here! :)  I have two requests before selecting ur answer as correct: 1- I think that `APIConnector` should be checked. `#get` is inside `#initialize` and `connection` should be `@connection`? 2- How do you use the native middleware for timeouts?

Comment: Updated to include an example of timeouts. Fixed the nested, but connection is right (there's an attr_reader at the top)